# Capture HandleUnauthorizedRequest in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC Core application. I have policy based authentication in my Project. Added `[Authorize]` attribute on all my controllers. My requirement is that whenever there is an Unauthrorized Access, i have to do some work. Because of this i have to override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`. But i am unable to find any way to get access to this method.

My requirement is that, all other `[Authorize]` attribute functionality should work as it is but whenever there is Unauthorized access i have to write it to log file and dump this in DB.

I am stuck, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cookie authenction, you can config the cookie AccessDenied event like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(config => {
        config.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            config.AccessDeniedPath = "Page Path"; //Add this line
            OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
            {
                //do some logging
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
                
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @mj1313, thats exactly what i was looking for. Just one issue, on this "OnRedirectToAccessDenied" event, i want to re-direct to a custom view(page). Currently, i am getting an empty page. Can you kindly explain how can i re-direct to a view with this "OnRedirectToAccessDenied" event. That would be a great favour.

Comment: There is a `AccessDeniedPath ` option in the CookieAuthenticationOptions. You can use it redirect to your custom page. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @mj1313, o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = new Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>(context =>
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                            return context.Response.CompleteAsync();
                        })
                    };

This code worked for me

Comment: i have to log this thing in Database. I am using Repository-Service pattern in my application. So, at this point (in Startup.cs) i can not access any repository or service. Do you have any idea how can i log this information in DB. I just want to do a service call whenever there is an unauthorized access request. I believe i have to bind a method to "OnRedirectToAccessDenied" event but unable to figure out yet that how can i bind a service method to this property. If you have any idea, that would be a great help for me.